# Java ReentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock thread ignores while condition

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

class CalendarUser extends Thread {

    public static final String[] WEEKDAYS = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    private static volatile int today = 0;
    private static ReentrantReadWriteLock marker = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private static Lock readMarker = marker.readLock();
    private static Lock writeMarker = marker.writeLock();

    public CalendarUser(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        while ( today < WEEKDAYS.length-1) {
            if (this.getName().contains("Writer")) { // update the shared calendar
                writeMarker.lock();
                System.out.println(this.getName()+" "+today);
                try {
                    today++;
                } catch (Exception e)
                {e.printStackTrace(); }
                {
                    writeMarker.unlock();
                }
            } else {
                readMarker.lock();
                try {
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    readMarker.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ReadWriteLockDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create ten reader threads
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            new CalendarUser("Reader-"+i).start();

        // ...but only two writer threads
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
            new CalendarUser("Writer-"+i).start();
    }
}
```

Output:

> Writer-0 0
>
> Writer-0 1
>
> Writer-0 2
>
> Writer-0 3
>
> Writer-0 4
>
> Writer-0 5
>
> Writer-1 6

Writer-0 exits the loop when `today = 6` . What I don't understand is that Writer-1 executes once when `today = 6`. How is that possible? How does it even enter the loop when the loop's condition is not satisfied? My intuition tells me it has something to do with JIT compiler.

Comment: You test `today < WEEKDAYS.length` without holding any locks. This means both writers are going to enter the `while` loop, enter the `if` branch, and then block on `writeMarker.lock()`. Then, most likely due to random chance, `Writer-0` manages to acquire the lock, release the lock, and then acquire the lock again over and over, until it breaks out of the `while` loop, before `Writer-1` manages to acquire the lock even once. Now `today == 6` but `Writer-1`, which has already entered the `while` loop, is still blocked on `writeMarker.lock()` and finally has a chance to acquire it...

Comment: Aha! Makes sense now. Thank you!